# Group Template that clips/deletes enclosed polylines to avoid overlaps

Tags: arcgis-pro, overlapping-features, template

I have a group template that creates a polygon with one feature template and a boundary made of of 2 point line features with another feature template. For the polygon, the template had an option to modify existing features to prevent overlap which has been working great, so when I add a new polygon that overlaps with an old polygon the old one is automatically clipped to the intersection lines with the new one.
The line template does not have this feature, so once the clipping has been done I have two polygons that don't overlap but then I still have all the original lines from the old polygon AND the new lines for the new adjacent boundaries.
Is there a way to automate cleaning up those leftover lines?
One option I'm thinking of is having some kind of rule (maybe a python process?) that recognizes when a polygon and the line features that share the same global ID no longer line up, those lines are deleted and new ones are generated along the new polygon boundaries. But I am worried about cost for this.
Another option might be to have a process that recognizes when a line has been "enclosed" by existing lines or polygons, adding a vertex to the line at that point, and then deleting the side of the line that is overlapped.

I haven't been about to find descriptions of tools/code examples I could accomplish either of these with but also I'm not really sure if those are even worth while directions to be researching in. I have access to Workflow Manager, Model Builder, arcpy, and FME. Any suggestions help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If anyone sees this and has a suggestion for how to make my question more specific/easier to answer please let me know, I feel like it was specific so I'm not sure if the bot is mistaken or not